# AWS Batch jobs stuck in PENDING when they `dependsOn`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I have an issue chaining **AWS Batch** jobs.

- There are 3 **Compute environments** (`CE_A`, `CE_B`, `CE_C`) and they have associated one **Job queue** each (`JQ_A`, `JQ_B`, `JQ_C`).
- There are 6 **Job definitions** (`JD_1`, `JD_2`, ..., `JD_6`).
- Let `<jqce>-<jd>-<name>` be a **Job** launched on job queue (or compute environment) `<jqce>` and with job definition `<jd>`. Example: `A-1-a`, `C-6-z`.
- I want to execute sequentially about 20 jobs (launched with different environment variables): `A-1-a`, `A-1-b`, `B-2-c`, `A-3-d`, `A-3-e`, `A-3-f`, ...
- For each job I specify the dependency on previous job with: 
  `params.dependsOn = [{ "jobId": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"}]` in `Batch.submitJob(params)`.
- The first two jobs `A-1-a` and `A-1-b` execute successfully after waiting few minutes for ressource allocation.
- The third job, `B-2-c` also executes successfully, after a some minutes of waiting for the Compute environment `CE_B` to be up.
- Meanwhile, the compute environment `CE_A` is turned off since no job has presented.

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM:**

- I expect at this point that `CE_B` goes down and `CE_A` goes up. **`CE_A` is not going up.**
- The `A-3-d` is never executed, 16 hours later it is still in `PENDING` status.

  - The `dependsOn` is ok, its dependency ended long time ago.
  - Without `dependsOn` the Batch runs ok, with the same environment variables and config.

**QUESTIONS**

- Did you face similar problems with `AWS Batch` and `dependsOn`?
- Is it possible to chain batches from different Job Queues?
- Is it possible to chain batches from different Compute Environments?
- Does the `params.dependsOn = [{ "jobId": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" }]` seem ok to you? It seems I do not have to set the `type` attribute [see array jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/array_jobs.html);

Answer (score 2):

> Does the params.dependsOn = [{ "jobId": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" }] seem ok to you? It seems I do not have to set the type attribute see array jobs;

Yes, type is only required when it's defined as an Array job. And the JobID you're providing is what was returned when you submitted the specific job?

> Is it possible to chain batches from different Job Queues?
>   Is it possible to chain batches from different Compute Environments?
>   You should be able to do it but I've never done that.
>
> Meanwhile, the compute environment CE_A is turned off since no job has presented.

So CE_A was running already and ran A-1-a, A-1-b already?

As I recall AWS checks every 10 minutes for certain statuses and people have run into cases where the system seems stuck.

You could set CE_A to always have a minimum of 1 CPU so it doesn't disappear or become difficult to get a version of.

Can you simply for testing purposes? Shorter actions, reducing Queues, etc

Consider checking the AWS forum on Batch. Not much activity there but worth an additional set of eyes.

Comment: Thanks. • The JobId was the one provided by the previous submitted job. • Yes, the `CE_A` was up and executed `A1a` and `A1b`, then `CE_B` executed next job, and the 4th job which was supposed to run on `CE_A` never moved from `PENDING` to `RUNNABLE` (thus no `CE_A` up again) • Keeping alive min 1 vcpus is not an acceptable solution, these batches should run on rare random days.

Comment: Running the same jobs on the same Job Queue (and the same Compute Environment) works ok.